# C# linq Perform join with default value if join returns null

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, join

I am trying to perform a join and I want default value if join returns null.

My code is :

```
MyVar = from parent in db.ParentTable
        join child1 in db.Child1 on parent.Id equals child1.ParentId into j1

        select new ParentClass
        {
          Id = Parent.Id,
          Name = Parent.Name,
          Children = from child1 in db.Child1
                     join rm in db.Table1 on Child1.ID equals rm.ChildId
                     where Child1.ParentId == parent.Id && rm.OperationId == Op.ID
                     select new Child
                     {
                      Name = child1.Name,
                      ID = child1.ID,
                      Flag = rm.Value
                     }
        }
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

structure of db is :
Parent table :

```
Id | Name
1  | A
2  | B
```

Child1 table :

```
ParentId | Id | Name
1        | 21 | A1
1        | 22 | A2
2        | 23 | A3
1        | 24 | A4
```

Table1 :

```
Id | Child1Id | Value | OpID
1  | 21       | False | 123
2  | 21       | False | 124
3  | 21       | true  | 125
4  | 22       | true  | 126
```

and so on..

Note : Multiple entries in Child1 can have same Parent and multiple entries in Table1 can have same Child1Id.

Question : If Children's join returns empty I want show my custom Object like this :

```
{
  Name = child1.Name,
  ID =   child1.ID,
  Flag = False
 }
```

This must be a default object if join returns empty array and should have child1.Name and ID. How Do I achieve that?

Comment: Looks like left-outer-join. If an element in the left collection has no matching element in the right collection, use a default element as match. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: I tried defaultIfEmpty, it still returns empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `left join` and in addition to add to the joining condition also the where clase of `Op.ID`:

```
Children = from child1 in db.Child1
           where child1.ParentId == parent.Id
           join rm in db.Table1 on new { child1.ID, OpId = Op.ID } equals new { rm.ChildId, rm.OperationId } into joint
           from rm in joint.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new Child
           {
               Name = child1.Name,
               ID = child1.ID,
               Flag = rm == null ? false : rm.Value
           }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it gives syntax error on `Op.ID` on line 'join rm in db.Table1 on new { child1.ID, Op.ID }' saying, `An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name`

Comment: @thewarri0r9 - see updated. Didn't notice the names were the same

Comment: You sir are awesome !! Thanks

Comment: @thewarri0r9 - glad it helped :)